# View of scrolling images

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I am relatively new to Objective-C and iOS development.

What I want to do is have it that I have an array of length 52 representing a deck of cards, with each value in the array corresponding to a card image. When a button is pressed, the card that comes out will appear in an image view (already done), as well as appear as the right most element in a horizontal scroll view.

I do not however know how to do this in Objective-C, neither the horizontal view nor the appending to the end (or right).

Any help will be much appreciated,
Thank you very much for your time.
AB

Comment: This question is too broad.  You need to work through some tutorials.

Comment: I have been on other areas, but I haven't been able to find any information regarding left to right scrolling over up and down, except how to prevent it (which isn't related to what I want to do). Any resources at all regarding this sort of area you can point me towards?

Comment: There is nothing special about scrolling left-right instead of up-down.  [Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html), [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html), [Scrolling sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called Paging with a UIScrollView. Download the "Page Control" Sample project by apple here :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795

Think of each page in that project as another card. You can add/subtract from it whilst the program is running. You can take a look at my open source "Dollar Bets" app on github for another example here:

https://github.com/Rich86man/Dollar-Bets

Check out MainViewController